# Accessing files on pc from android

Tags: android

I'm new at android developing and wanted to make a little tool.

I would need to give my tool a path, like C://my/path

Then my app goes to that path and does something like copying some file on the phone, checking its mime type, its size, some other attributes.

Is this possible?

I don't want a Windows Explorer-like app or something like that. I just need to do some simple file manipulations.

Comment: I believe that would require the phone to be USB Host capable?  I don't think that's possible without a hardware hack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither your device nor your emulator can access files on your PC via USB. You are welcome to implement this using WiFi, or perhaps Bluetooth, but this will be **far** from "a little tool".

Comment: Okay. :( But the other way round shouldnt be a problem right?

Comment: @xotix: You cannot access files on a device from an attached PC except for whatever external storage is mounted.